# Finding a scale that gives integer values after multiplication to a given set of integers

Tags: number-theory

Here goes the question: Let say I have two integers, $A$ and $B$.
And I want to find a real number $x$ ($0\lt x\lt 1$) which satisfies

$$   A * x = A'\\
    B * x = B'$$

where $A'$ and $B'$ are both integers and $A'$ is the biggest possible value for any given $x$ ($0\lt x\lt1$)

Is there a general solution for this problem?

Comment: If $A \cdot x = A'$ and $B \cdot x = B'$ are both integers, then $A \cdot nx = nA'$ and $B \cdot nx = nB'$ are also integers for any positive integer $n$ and $nA' > A'$. Hence, if there is at least one value of $x$ which works, then there is no biggest possible value of $A'$. EDIT: Now that the question has been edited to specify $0 < x < 1$, this is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, $x$ must be rational, so let $x= \dfrac{p}{q}$ for positive integers $0 < p < q$ with $\text{gcd}(p,q) = 1$.

Since $A' = A \cdot x = \dfrac{Ap}{q}$ and $B' = B \cdot x = \dfrac{Bp}{q}$ are integers, $q \mid Ap$ and $q \mid Bp$.

Then, since $\text{gcd}(p,q) = 1$, we must have $q \mid A$ and $q \mid B$. Hence, $q \mid \text{gcd}(A,B)$.

If $q \mid \text{gcd}(A,B)$, then $q \mid A$ and $q \mid B$, and thus, $\dfrac{Ap}{q}$ and $\dfrac{Bp}{q}$ are integers, so this is sufficient.

For any fixed $q$, the largest possible value of $x = \dfrac{p}{q}$ such that $0 < x < 1$ is $x = 1-\dfrac{1}{q}$.

The largest possible value of $x = 1-\dfrac{1}{q}$ such that $q \mid \text{gcd}(A,B)$ is obtained for $q = \text{gcd}(A,B)$, i.e. $x = 1-\dfrac{1}{\text{gcd}(A,B)}$.